# initWithDelegate for Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have import this Objective-C class in a swift project. 
**MMLANSCanner.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Device;
@protocol MMLANScannerDelegate;
@protocol MMLANScannerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)lanScanDidFinishScanningWithStatus:(MMLanScannerStatus)status;
- (void)lanScanDidFailedToScan;
@optional
- (void)lanScanProgressPinged:(float)pingedHosts from:(NSInteger)overallHosts;
@end

#pragma mark - Public methods
@interface MMLANScanner : NSObject
-(instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id <MMLANScannerDelegate>)delegate;
@property(nonatomic,weak) id<MMLANScannerDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic,assign,readonly)BOOL isScanning;
- (void)start;
- (void)stop;
@end
```

I successfully created the bridging header and make the MainVC.Swift to conform to MMLANScannerDelegate.
Then I tried to initialise the MMLanScanner with delegate `self`.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MainVC: UIViewController, MMLANScannerDelegate {

    var presenter = MMLANScanner(delegate:self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func lanScanDidFindNewDevice(_ device: Device!) {

    }

    func lanScanDidFailedToScan() {

    }

    func lanScanDidFinishScanning(with status: MMLanScannerStatus) {

    }

    func lanScanProgressPinged(_ pingedHosts: Float, from overallHosts: Int) {

    }
}
```

But I get error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Any ideas how to implement initWithDelegate function that I had in Objective-C?

Comment: Can you please explain why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MLANScanner` doesn't take a `delegate` argument to its `init` method (`delegate` is a *property* of `MLANScanner`).

You also have a problem with the definition of your `presenter` property since `self` isn't valid at the time `MainVC` is created.

Do this instead:

```
let presenter = MLANScanner()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    presenter.delegate = self
}
```

based on edit to question:

```
var presenter: MLANScanner!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    presenter = MLANScanner(delegate: self)
}
```

Note: My edited answer assumes there is a Swift bridge somewhere that exposes an `init(delegate:)` method.  There may not be and making one is beyond the scope of this question.  Since the delegate is not private or read-only you can almost certainly use the first version I posted.

Comment: I tried that but initWithDelegate wasn't called at all.

Comment: MMLANScanner takes a delegate in it's method. I deleted accidentally. Check the update question please. (Sorry)

Comment: You probably don't need to call `initWithDelegate` the answer I posted will do what you want, but see my update for a possible alternate.

Comment: Actually I need it because initWithDelegate calls [super init] and does some other initialisation.